# How to pass props through useRoutes in react hook router?

Tags: reactjs, hookrouter

I'm new to react and react hooks. I'm using react-hooks for one of my project. I'm using *hookrouter* package and I tried to googling about the question, but didn't find much help.

**What I want?**

I'm trying to pass props through hook routes in react. e.g. , I want to pass object through `useRoutes(routes)`.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I got the answer. You can pass the props to the desired component inside the router.js file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I was confused and was thinking of passing `props` through `useRoutes` instead of Components individually inside `routes`. [Doc](https://github.com/Paratron/hookrouter)

```
const routes = {
    '/': () => <HomePage />,
    '/about': () => <AboutPage props={yourProps} />,
    '/products': () => <ProductOverview props={yourProps} />,
    '/products/:id': ({id}) => <ProductDetails id={id} />
};

const MyApp = () => {
    const routeResult = useRoutes(routes);

    return routeResult || <NotFoundPage />;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly:

**router.js**

```
import React from "react";
import Users from "./components/Users";
import Contact from "./components/Contact";
import About from "./components/About";
const routes = {
  "/": () => <Users />,
  "/about": () => <About />,
  "/contact": () => <Contact />
};
export default routes;
```

then:

**App/index.js**

```
import {useRoutes} from 'hookrouter';
import Routes from './router'

function App() {
  const routeResult = useRoutes(Routes)
  return routeResult
}
```

For more information please read here - https://blog.logrocket.com/how-react-hooks-can-replace-react-router/

Answer (score 0):

I have been doing something like that:

**RoutePropsContext.js**

```
import React from 'react';

const RoutePropsContext = React.createContext(null);

export default RoutePropsContext;
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <App/>
  </Router>

  ,document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import RoutePropsContext from '@helpers/context/RoutePropsContext';

function App(props) {

  const routeProps = {
    match: props.match,
    location: props.location,
    history: props.history
  };

  return(
    <RoutePropsContext.Provider value={routeProps}>
      <YourApp/>
    </RoutePropsContext.Provider>
  );

}

export default withRouter(App);
```

**useRouteProps.js**

```
import {useContext} from 'react';
import RoutePropsContext from '../context/RoutePropsContext';

function useRouteProps() {
  const routeProps = useContext(RoutePropsContext);
  return ({
    ...routeProps
  });
}

export default useRouteProps;
```

**Component_Using_the_Hook.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import useRouteProps from './hooks/useRouteProps';

function SomeComponent() {
  const {match, location, history} = useRouteProps();

  return(
    <Something/>
  );
}

export default SomeComponent;
```